# Save Json to online database GAE or Firebase

Tags: json, google-app-engine, database-connection, firebase

I am new to JSON and online databases. I have learned the basics of using .js files and manipulation on them. But I have no clue how to save them onto GAE or Firebase databases.

1)My question is, are every online databases uses JSON differently when they store them?

I have no idea what it looks like storing onto an online database so

2)Can you give me an example of JSON stored in Firebase or GAE. Links to tutorials are also helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase is a true "online database" in a sense that you can save/retrieve/query data to it, without actually writing any code on the server. As such, it is close to Backend as a Service offerings, such as Parse, Kinvey, etc.. Search the web to find more services and [compare features that you need](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2842791/application-development/mbaas-shoot-out-5-cloud-platforms-for-building-mobile-apps.html).

OTOH, GAE is an application platform - you will need to write server-side code to create any functionality.

As for examples: please [RTFM](https://www.firebase.com/how-it-works.html).

Answer (score 1):

GAE's ndb datastore API has a JsonProperty:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties

It's easy to store a JSON object as a StringProperty, using json.loads, json.dumps to parse.  For a simple list, you can use a StringProperty, and giving it the `repeated=True` tag:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#repeated